# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 installing library

Tags: c++, c, computer-science, scientific-computing, gsl

I'm trying to install GSL on OS X 10.9.3. 
I had followed all the installation steps mentioned. But I keep getting this error.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___sincos_stret", referenced from:
      _city_distance in siman_tsp.o
      _prepare_distance_matrix in siman_tsp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be great!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt0nv.png

Comment: Seems like you only built the 32 bit option but linked it 64 bit code.

Comment: i don't think that was the case as makefile and all files are generated automatically. just solved this by updating my xcode. I think the compiler was outdated. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Xcode could not find the headers.

Answer (score 0):

just solved this by updating my xcode. I think the compiler was outdated. but thanks anyway. – user3466563